# Can't import a *.py file. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'w_web_page'**

Tags: python, import, virtualenv

I shall appreciate your answer about this problem:

I have 2 files, `w_web_page.ui` and `w_web_page.py` in the same folder inside the same venv: `C:\Users\Usuario\venv\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5`

When I enter:

```py
from w_web_page import
```

I get error:

> File "", line 3, in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'w_web_page'

On Windows 7, I am using:

```
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May 3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

PyQt5_gpl-5.11.3

PyScripter 4.1.1
```

I can not realise why it does not find the file to import.

Comment: Don't store your own files in `site-packages`.

Comment: Can you explain us why this file is in `site-packages\PyQt5`? And which file has `from w_web_page import *`.